# How to get full loaded HTML source from web site in a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I need the same source i can find in the Elements window of DevTool console in my extension. I tried using the content script

```
var text = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

injected after catched the "complete"  status from `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener`, but i recived only the html code without the content dynamically created.

In particular i want my extension to find all "div" added dynamically.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `complete` event fires once the initial page content has been loaded. It has no relation to dynamically generated content, otherwise it would have to wait indefinitely, since more content may always be added later.

If you are interested in a specific element, you can use `setTimeout` to periodically poll for the element. Like so:

```
function getElement() {
    return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            var elm = document.getElementById('the-element-you-want');
            if(elm){
                clearInterval(interval);
                res(elm);
            }
        }, 10);
    });
}
```

Another option would be to use a `MutationObserver` to detect when the desired element(s) have been created.

Comment: I don't know the element's name but i need to search for a specific text usually contained in Iframe or in a div. Also, i need exactly what is generated since the status == complete.
I need to parse the entire text for some match (what i need usually is not in the basic DOM but is displayed on the page). I hope I made myself clear.
The fact is i see some different between the DOM of the site and what i actually see in the page!

Thank you!

Comment: @EugenioNerioNemmi In that case you can either use `setTimeout` to periodically check if that texts exists yet. Or, using `mutationObserver`, check all new elements to see if they contain the desired text. Once you know the text exists, you can go ahead and parse the entire DOM.

Comment: Solved it! Thank you very much, you were helpful!